# How to hook comment forbidden link?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm using [views 3](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to show a page.

I added a header to this view ("global: text area"), in whom I added a field/link "add comment" with token.

My problem: when the current user is not connected, I have a message of type: `Log in or register to post comments`.

I would like to keep the text link "add comment", which sends back to the page of connection.

I tried to modify the view field template, but it does'nt work.

I try to use `function THEME_node_view_alter (&$build) {unset($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment_forbidden']);}` in a custom module, but it does'nt work too.

I found that it came of [theme_comment_post_forbidden](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/theme_comment_post_forbidden/7.x), but I do not know how to modify it.

Do you know how can it be done?